# regular expression use ( ) to search instand of indicate group

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I want to get the stuff back between the ( and ).

But ( ) are used for groups, and with the escape \ i get the error:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\(.*\))");
```

unexpected char: '('

How can i prevent this?

> Wed 13 Oct 2010 20:00:11 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Tue 12 Oct 2010 21:27:48 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Tue 12 Oct 2010 04:44:57 +0200 (West-Europa (zomertijd))
>
> Tue 12 Oct 2010 03:10:22 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Mon 11 Oct 2010 23:10:04 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Mon 11 Oct 2010 20:56:27 +0200 (CEST)

(I used java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java strings, you have to escape the `'\\'` character, try:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(.*\\))");
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works great, also the one of sidyll works great.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to escape the backslashes; also I think you want the escape in a different position (and better be more specific about what you want to match):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*)\\)");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\\(     # literal (
(       # start capturing group
 [^()]* # any number of characters except parentheses
)       # end capturing group
\\)     # literal )
```

Comment: +1 This expression correctly matches all "innermost" matching parentheses when they are nested. (The lazy-dot-star version fails when the parens are nessted.)

Comment: This one went wrong on
(West-Europa (zomertijd))
but thanks for explanation!

Comment: Right. If you always want to capture the outermost pair of parentheses, and if there is never more than one pair of parentheses at the same nesting level, then `.*` instead of `[^()]*` is better. But only then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the escape:

```
"(\\(.*?\\))"
```

Note that I also used the un-greedy version of "match anything".

The double escape is because within a string literal, the backslash is used for escape sequences (like `\n`) so if you want a backslash in your string, you need to escape it with another backslash.

Comment: Non-greedy can still give you unexpected results if the input data isn't very nice (e.g., for `foo (bar (boo) hoo)` you'd match `(bar (boo)`).